# C# to get facebook status

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth

**Simply put:** I would like my application to go off and give me the latest facebook status update(or two) for a single user(me). IE: My website blah.com will display my own status update(with a like button if possible).

**Added Complexity**: I have read the following api http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ {https://graph.facebook.com/[your facebook id]/feed} with little success of retrieving my status, unless i turn off my privacy settings. I would like to leave these as is for my test application as I don't think i can tell the client to make theirs public.

Where are we now: That leaves setting up with OAuth or using a 3rd party wrapper. I have had little success with the latter and am not skilled enough to set up with oauth.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just uploaded some source to github if you are interested. It's a little project to help with Facebook's Graph API. Feel free to check it out [here](https://github.com/HopDizzle/NET-Facebook-API). Its not the most scalable code, but it does the trick.

Comment: Thanks heaps dude. If i'm reading it right you are making a server side request to the graph API, getting the the access token in the response and applying it to subsequent requests that need to be validated. I would not worry about your code being scalable as Facebook will probably change the way their API works next week!!  Wish i could up vote twice for the effort you put in. I may actually use this on another part of the project.

Comment: @Kieran I'm glad the code can be of some use to you. You pretty much hit the nail on the head. Let me know if you have any issues and feel free to use the code where ever.

Answer (score 1):

Why not grab it via RSS? Go here:

http://www.facebook.com/notifications.php

and click on the 'Via RSS' link to go to your notifications feed, and simply change 'notifications.php' in the URL to 'status.php'.

You should then  be able to grab this feed in to an XmlDocument and check out the first item node.

Comment: awesome and very simple solution to the problem. my only issue with this is does the key param in the query string expire?

Comment: This works for my personal account but when i use it on the clients account i get this message. This feed URL is no longer valid. Visit this page to find the new URL, if you have access, http://www.facebook.com/feeds/status.php?id=x&viewer=x&key=x&format=rss20